# How do I migrate accounts?

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to migrate user accounts from a Drupal 7 site to a Drupal 8 site.

On the Drupal 8 site, I have a module that programmatically adds users using the following code.

```
$user = User::create();
$user->uid = '';
$user->setUsername('test');
$user->setEmail('test@abc.com');
$user->set("pass", $S$E96L22SibwKw5GrZrrCqCz7mxSjr9Z2pSB3GqBs5eeheTBPxOlJc); /*hashed value*/
$user->save();
```

The module creates the accounts correctly, but the user passwords are re-hashed.

Comment: Don't hash the password in this line: `$user->set("pass", $S$E96L22SibwKw5GrZrrCqCz7mxSjr9Z2pSB3GqBs5eeheTBPxOlJc);`. Use an unhashed value.

Comment: @Jaypan you are the right man. But I have 1000 user from my another drupal site.

So that, I want to save hashed password.

Comment: @Jaypan I know when a user saves with a password. drupal automatically convert plaintext to hashed

Comment: It won't work - Drupal adds a hash salt to hashes, so unless you included that salt when creating your hashes, it wouldn't work. And since you are migrating your users from a different system, they won't have that salt. For this situation you can force your users to recover their password on the new system after migration, by sending out the password reset mail.

Comment: @Jaypan No no, I have Drupal 7 sites so that is not a different system. When I have manually try drupal 7 passwords. it is worked.

Comment: @Jaypan I am not able to force my users to a password reset. Otherwise `_user_mail_notify()` useful.

Comment: I did a search on this and came across the following. Can you please try and see if this works? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209163/how-do-i-migrate-users-passwords You can also check out Migrate API https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users-advanced-password

Comment: Definitely do this with the Migrate API.

Comment: You can use this code: `$database = \Drupal::database(); $database->merge('users_field_data') ->fields(['pass' => 'YOUR_D7_HASH_HERE'])->keys(array('uid' => THE_USER_ID_HERE))->execute();` See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209163/how-do-i-migrate-users-passwords.