# How to migrate password with hash

Tags: users, migrations

I'm doing a user migration from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 (the data is in json format) 
Most of the fields have been imported to the new website. Now, I'm in the process to migrate the password; this field is, of course, encrypted/hashed (as far as I understood, Drupal uses SHA512 by default with a salt).

So far, I have found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294074/migrate-users-and-retain-passwords) answer and adapted my code like below:

```
$users_json = file_get_contents("../import/users.json");
$users_array = json_decode($users_json, true);

foreach($users_array as $user){

    $values = array(
        'name' => $user["name"],
        'pass' => [
            'value' => $user["pass"],
            'pre_hashed' => TRUE,
        ],
        'status' => $user["status"],
        'mail' => $user["mail"],
    );
    
    $userStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');
    $userEntity = $userStorage->create($values);
    
    $role = $user["roles"][0];
    $userEntity->addRole($role);

}
```

Now, my question is: Is it a good approach? How do I import this kind of field? Do I have to decrypt/de-hash the password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I migrate users passwords?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209163/how-do-i-migrate-users-passwords)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow [document](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users-advanced-password).

> The $P$ is the so called hash type identifier which indicates that the
> hash is a portable Phpass hash. The string after that consists of salt
> and a hash. The portable Phpass hashes can be migrated to Drupal 8
> as-is. When the user logs in to your Drupal 8 site for the first time,
> Drupal will re-hash the password. The salted hash used in this example
> is for a password 'test'.

> If the source system was a PHP based application that used crypt() or
> password_hash(), these hashes should work as-is and they can be
> migrated 1:1 like in the Phpass example above. When the user logs in
> to your Drupal 8 site for the first time, Drupal will re-hash the
> password.

Here is my example convert old pass using **md5**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\Password\PhpassHashedPassword;
use Drupal\Core\Password\PasswordInterface;

/**
 * Provides custom password hash comparison for migrated passwords.
 */
class MyModulePasswordService extends PhpassHashedPassword implements PasswordInterface {


  public function check ($password, $hash) {
    // Check old pass is md5
    if (preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/', $hash)) {
      $pwd_sercet = "pwd_sercet";
      $pass_hash = md5($pwd_sercet . $password);
      return ($pass_hash == $hash);
    }
    return parent::check($password, $hash);
  }
}
```