# How can you require users to change their passwords on first login after migration?

Tags: users, migrations, 9

We are planning to migrate users from another CMS to Drupal. We can migrate usernames, but not passwords as the encryption is different. So we shall have to assign passwords to them. Earlier versions of Drupal had the ability to force a password change at first logon, but Drupal 9 seems to have lost it?  What am I missing?  People have answered the question before, but, as I said, not for Drupal 9.

Comment: Drupal 8, 9 already supported old encryption, so you don't need require change password. You can follow [document](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users-advanced-password). I checked, still working with drupal 9.

Comment: Thanks - I looked at the document.  It mentions crypt, phpcache and Blowfish algorithms.  It looks as though our implementation is using Blowfish, but simply copying the hash to Drupal doesn't work.  Any suggestions.

In any case, if you set up a new user or reset a password for a user, you want to force a password change, don't you, and Drupal 9 doesn't seem to do so?

Comment: Document mentions create a module provide a custom password service too. So you have to create a custom module to check old hash password.

Comment: A example I convert from old password use md5 https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299508/how-to-migrate-password-with-hash

Comment: I found that running

composer require drupal/php_password:1.2.0

enabling PHP Password and restarting the site seemed to do the job.  It still doesn't answer the question about forcing password changes for new users.

Comment: I mean that you don't need create new password for user. Just migrate hash password and use still using old password.

Comment: For that you can script something with https://www.drupal.org/project/force_password_change @StephenPalmstrom

Comment: I have solved the password migration problem.  @Clive Does https://www.drupal.org/project/force_password_change work with Drupal 9?